# Adding consecutive elements of ArrayList

Tags: list

I am trying to achieve the following:

> Given a list {146,7,-2,-1} write a new list such that its ith element consists of sums of "i" and i+1".

So this list: {146,153,151,150} would be transformed into 146 as 146+7=153, 153+(-2)=151 and so on.
I wrote the following:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

list2.add(0, list.get(0));

for(int i=0;i<list.size()-1;i++)
{
  list2.add(i+1, list.get(i+1)+list.get(i));
  System.out.println(list2);
}
```

However, this is returning {146,153,6,-3}. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be adding to `list2.get(i)` instead of `list.get(i)`

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list2.add(0, list.get(0));

for(int i=0;i<list.size()-1;i++)
{
    list2.add(i+1, list.get(i+1)+list2.get(i));
    System.out.println(list2);

}
```