# difference of two consecutive values in an ArrayList: Android

Tags: android, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList()` which stores some data generated at real time. I want to get the difference of the consecutive element of the `ArrayList`

1. I tried this

   ```
   ArrayList<Long> difference = new ArrayList<>();
   difference.add(durationInMs);
   //tried to store 
   for (int d = 0; d < difference.size()-1; d++){
           time1 = difference.get(d);
           time2 = difference.get(d + 1);
           timeDifference = time2 - time1;
   }
   ```
2. This:----------------

   ```
   ArrayList<Long> difference = new ArrayList<>();
   difference.add(durationInMs);

   ArrayList<Long> tempArray = new ArrayList<>();
   tempArray.add(0, difference.get(0));

   for (int d = 0; d < difference.size()-1; d++){
           timeDifference = tempArray.get(d+1) - difference.get(d);
   }
   Log.d("time", String.valueOf(timeDifference));
   ```
3. Also this
   [enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26292211/adding-consecutive-elements-of-arraylist)

But non of them seems to get me the subtracted value between 2 consecutive elements. Probably the problem is the values are generating in real time and this when subtracting, the next value is not yet generated.
How do i do it?

**UPDATE: the method (if it helps)**

```
@Override
public void onPreviewFrame(long startTime, int ySum, int uSum, int vSum, long endTime) {
    begin = startTime;
    img_Y_Avg = ySum;
    img_U_Avg = uSum;
    img_V_Avg = vSum;
    end = endTime;


    //set value of Y on the text view
    TextView valueOfY = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.valueY);
    //valueY = img_Y_Avg;
    valueOfY.setText(Double.toString(img_Y_Avg));

    //set value of U on the text view
    TextView valueOfU = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.valueU);
   // valueU = img_U_Avg;
    valueOfU.setText(Double.toString(img_U_Avg));

    //set value of V on the text view
    TextView valueOfV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.valueV);
    //valueV = img_V_Avg;
    valueOfV.setText(Double.toString(img_V_Avg));

    //start time in milliseconds
    long StartDurationInMs = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(begin, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    ArrayList<Long> startOfTime = new ArrayList<>();
    startOfTime.add(StartDurationInMs);
    Log.d("time", "start: "+String.valueOf(startOfTime));

    //store value to array list
    ArrayList<Integer> yAverage = new ArrayList<>();
    yAverage.add(img_Y_Avg);
    //Log.d("MyEntryData", String.valueOf(yAverage));

    //store u values to array
    ArrayList<Integer> uAverage = new ArrayList<>();
    uAverage.add(img_U_Avg);
    //Log.d("MyEntryData", String.valueOf(uAverage));

    //store u values to array
    ArrayList<Integer> vAverage = new ArrayList<>();
    vAverage.add(img_V_Avg);
    //Log.d("MyEntryData", String.valueOf(vAverage));
    //time between frames

    //end time in milliseconds
    long EndDurationInMs = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(end, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    ArrayList<Long> endOfTime = new ArrayList<>();
    endOfTime.add(EndDurationInMs);


    Log.d("time", "end: "+String.valueOf(endOfTime));


    ArrayList<Long> getValues = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < yAverage.size(); i++) {
        getValues.add(startOfTime.get(i));
        getValues.add((long)(yAverage.get(i)));
        getValues.add((long)(uAverage.get(i)));
        getValues.add((long)(vAverage.get(i)));
    }


    String filename = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmm'.csv'").format(new Date());

    File directoryDownload = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
    File logDir = new File (directoryDownload, "bpReader"); //Creates a new folder in DOWNLOAD directory
    logDir.mkdirs();
    File file = new File(logDir, filename);

    FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
    try {
           outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file, true);
           //outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
           for (int i = 0; i < yAverage.size(); i += 4) {
               outputStream.write((getValues.get(i) + ",").getBytes());
               outputStream.write((getValues.get(i + 1) + ",").getBytes());
               outputStream.write((getValues.get(i + 2) + ",").getBytes());
               outputStream.write((getValues.get(i + 3) + "\n").getBytes());

            }
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    Log.d("MyEntryData", String.valueOf(getValues));


    handler = new Handler();
    final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            readingRemaining = readingRemaining -1;

            if (readingRemaining > 0){
                plotGraph(img_Y_Avg);
            }
        }
    };

    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 100);

    //Log.d("MyEntryData", String.valueOf(img_Y_Avg +" "+ img_U_Avg+" "+img_V_Avg));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try long delta = difference.get(d+1) - difference.get(d);

```
    ArrayList<Long> difference = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i<10; i++)
        difference.add((long)(Math.random() * 1000));
    for (int d = 0; d < difference.size()-1; d++){
        Log.i("diff", String.format(
                "element %d,%d:%d - %d = %d",
                d+1, d, difference.get(d+1), difference.get(d),
                difference.get(d+1) - difference.get(d)));
    }
    Log.i(TAG, "hello");
```

Output:

```
... I/diff: element 1,0:197 - 425 = -228
... I/diff: element 2,1:389 - 197 = 192
... I/diff: element 3,2:947 - 389 = 558
... I/diff: element 4,3:510 - 947 = -437
... I/diff: element 5,4:399 - 510 = -111
... I/diff: element 6,5:971 - 399 = 572
... I/diff: element 7,6:537 - 971 = -434
... I/diff: element 8,7:326 - 537 = -211
... I/diff: element 9,8:897 - 326 = 571
```

Comment: nothing shows in logcat. probably because can not call a log function inside a for loop. it happened to me a couple of times earlier.

Comment: @Mill3r,  since when can't you print Log within a loop.  That's new to me and it works with the example code.

Comment: I'm sorry may be I'm wrong.
i have found the real problem in my case. Since I'm getting the image processing data from `onPrevieFrame` in real time, its just sending 1 set of data each time for each frame. I logged out the `yAverage.size()` and found the size always remains 1. its not increasing. Hence when I'm trying to find the difference between index `i` and `i+1` in the loop, I'm getting en error, because there is no `i+1` to begin with.
thank you for your help..

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned that the array is being modified real-time as your are processing it, then

**Suggestion 1**

At the time a new data point is generated, could you look at the prior data point and calculate delta on-the-fly, then add() the delta to another array?

```
  long lastDatum = null;
  ArrayList<long> diffArray = new ArrayList<>();

  void recordDataPoint(long datum)
  { 
      if (lastDatum != null) {
         diffArray.add(datum - lastDatum);
      }
      lastDatum = datum;

      // ... do whatever else you need to do with datum....
   }
```

**Suggestion 2**
If the array is stable then I think you just need to do this:

```
  // existing data is in durationInMs[]

  ArrayList<Long> difference = new ArrayList<>();

  for (int d = 0; d < durationInMs.size()-1; d++){
        time1 = durationInMs.get(d);
        time2 = durationInMs.get(d + 1);
        timeDifference = time2 - time1;

        difference.add(timeDifference);
}
```

Comment: i did not actually understand what you are trying to do.  I got the concept what your trying to say but the code you wrote....
is it that you are creating another method or something like that to do the calculations?

Comment: Sorry if it isn't clear. You mentioned that you are real-time saving data into an array. I am suggesting perhaps saving the (time1-time2), real time, into a new array of differences might help you, rather than post-processing it.

Comment: `ArrayList<Long> difference = new ArrayList<>();
        difference.add(durationInMs);

        ArrayList<Long> tempArray = new ArrayList<>();
        tempArray.add(0, difference.get(0));

        for (int d = 1; d < difference.size()-1; d++){
            if (difference != null){
                time1 = difference.get(d-1);
                time2 = tempArray.get(d);
                timeDifference = time2 - time1;
            }
        }`
here im storing the values into a temporary array. time1 = index 2; time2 = index1; timeElapsed = time2 - time1;

something like this?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your problem. I thought you are concerned that the array is being modified while you are trying to calculate the differences (get(i+1) - get(i)). If so,then storing the differences as the new values arrive should work.

Comment: my apologies. My mistake i cant explain it clearly. Ill try once again,
I am having an ArrayList which is storing some real time values (the time between generating 2 frames from the camera view). I have set the camera view to 16 fps so the time should be around 50-70 milliseconds. 
Now, to measure that i have used a start and end `System.nanoTime()` and stored the end time into an ArrayList. The value generated is perfectly fine. ex. [103611894], [103611936], etc. and the difference is also correct (42 here). I need to get that difference and store it into a variable to do further analysis.

Comment: i have update my question with the full method. if that helps. please check. Want to find the difference between start time and end time.
1. `StartTime` and `EndTime` are generating same value. 2. difference between two consecutive `StartTime` is the value i need. 3. Since the values are generated in real-time, `startOfTime.size()` always returns **1**.  
4. So, if i subtract (startOfTime.get(d) - startOfTime(d+1)) i get 0. 
is there a way to store all of these values first.. and then do the iteration?